# who assigns event/interface id for handling in epoll_wait()

Tags: c++, c, linux, epoll

This question bugs me from long time. 
I want to know, in case of `event polling` mechanism. When I have a code in which I say I have 3 FDs to poll and I have assigned each `interface type` to each FD by which the event will be identified. The handling is also done using `epoll_create()`, then reception of events using `epoll_wait()`.

```
Say: 3 FDs. 
1 Timer, 1 IPC, 1 MQTT -> Creation using epoll_create
```

But my question is who assigns the event id or interface id to the external event as the category of events and their respective interface will always be internal.

Please let me know if my question is clear or not.

Comment: To me, your question, as well as your answer, is not clear. That is because you are using terms which are defined neither in the epoll documentation nor by you:
1. interface type;
2. event id;
3. interface id;
4. external event;
5. category of events;
6. internal.
Perhaps your terms correspond to notions in the epoll documentation; if so, you should use the documentation's wording.

Comment: @Armali Considering int epoll_wait(int epfd, struct epoll_event *events, int maxevents, int timeout); 1. Interface type:*events, 2.Event ID: corresponding to *events, 3.Interface ID: fd considering "epoll_ctl(int epfd, int op, int fd, struct epoll_event *event);", 4.External events: Any msg coming to module X where epoll is implemented, 5.category of event: which FD should handle an event, 6.Internal:module specific implementation.

Comment: You should have been able to use the consistent terminology from the manual pages instead of inventing your own. It is  counterproductive to call 1. events "interface type"; 2. something corresponding to events "ID"; 3. a file descriptor "interface id"; 5. a file descriptor "category". Your definitions 4. and 6. are legitimate; you should also consider including them in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer.

Say there are `3 FDs` created: `1 Timer, 1 IPC & 1 MQTT.`
When these are created then subsequent interfaces are assigned to each interface FD which is inturn added to Poll FD.
**Any event happening on each interface ID will be read by Poll FD and for which interface it happened will be known.**

That's how it will be known for which interface is the event meant. Its not the case that any external module assigns the epoll interface ID, its rather handled internally.

Comment: There are undefined or inappropriately used terms: 1. interface; 2. Poll FD; 3. interface ID; 4. external module.